# How to redirect to homepage when certain string is in the url

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to redirect an URL that has the word "guest" in it, so example:
`https://example/web/mxOYPIE6cpymvkM5TEGMvI4UYXXQT4WTMEaDrE5q7eo%5B*/!STANDARD?pyActivity=Data-Admin-Operator-ID%2epxGetAllOperators&pzAuth=guest`

And it needs to redirect to:
`https://example/web/LDAP`

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} guest [NC]  
RewriteRule .* https://example/web/LDAP [L,R=301]
```

But this will redirect it to:
`https://example/web/LDAP?mxOYPIE6cpymvkM5TEGMvI4UYXXQT4WTMEaDrE5q7eo%5B*/!STANDARD?pyActivity=Data-Admin-Operator-ID%2epxGetAllOperators&pzAuth=guest`

So the complete string behind https://example/web/ gets pasted behind https://example/web/LDAP

And if I do it like this, people will get a 403, but that's not very professional.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} guest [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If apache version is 2.4.0 or later, you can use QSD Flag like below.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} guest [NC]  
RewriteRule .* /web/LDAP [L,R=301,QSD]
```

refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: I use the IHS from IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.15, if I use the QSD flag I get an error: RewriteRule: unknown flag 'QSD'